# Travelling (soliton) Wave solution to 1D GPE equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, quantum-mechanics, wave-equation

I have a non-dimensional version of the Gross-Pitaevskii equation:
$$ 2i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = - \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} + \left|\psi \right|^2\psi -\psi, $$
where $\psi(x,t)$ is the wave-function for a BEC. My aim is to find a travelling wave solution. I suspect this solution is of the form:
$$\psi(x,t) = f(x-ut)\,e^{-i\mu t}  ,$$ where $\mu, u$ are constants ($u$ is the speed).
From reading around online (specifically, the book "A Primer on Quantum Fluids"), I think the final solution for $\psi(x,t)$ is of the general form:
$$ \psi(x,t) = \tanh\left( (x-ct)\,+i\frac{u}{c} \right)\,e^{-i\mu t}. $$
I have tried to substitute my form of the solution into it to find $f$, and so far I am at the current stage:
$$ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} - i\,2u\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -f^3 +(1+2\mu)f = 0,$$
but after carrying on with this and applying some basic differential equation solver techniques, it doesn't seem to get me to the right place. It is also possible that I have made mistakes leading up to this point, and I'm not too sure whether that's the case or where to go from here. This particular solution is for dark solitons. I also need to find bright soliton solutions but this should proceed in a similar manner. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would help to state what $f$ you've inferred. (We can judge what it should be, but we can't guess what you think it is.) Edit: Actually, a more basic concern: $\tanh((x-ct)+i u/c)$ does not seem to have sensible units. One would need to instead have $(x-ct)/\xi$ for some length scale $\xi$. Glancing at the arXiv version of your source, should it in fact be $(\tanh[(x-ut)/\xi]+i u/c)e^{-i \mu t}$?

Comment: I'm not certain that the conjectured solution is an exact one, by substituting it into the first equation, I find some terms remain (perhaps I've made algebraic errors?). Do you know if the general form of the solution is exact, or under what conditions it was derived?

Comment: Looking at that source again, it seems like the "dark soliton" solution I was referencing was specifically a solution to the "zero potential" case of the GP equation. So it's not obvious whether your case has an exact solution. (Your case amounts to a nonzero chemical potential. In the Schrodinger equation that'd be irrelevant, but the nonlinear nature of the GP equation means that this change is nontrivial.)

Comment: Googling quickly, it seems that indeed there is no exact solution in the case of potential $\mu\neq 0$. So the best one can hope for is seemingly either numerical work or perturbative calculations. (See for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.3840v1.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, having checked, I've made a mistake and the solution should be 
$ ( \tanh \left[ (x-ut) / \xi  \right] + i \, u/c) e^{-i\mu t} $. I'm not sure if I'd need the $ \xi $ term though, since my equation is in non-dimensional units? Whereas the equation (4.38) in the source is for dimensional units?

Comment: @Semiclassical the arxiv link you posted isn't working for me. That there is no exact solution is reasonable.

Comment: @Sal The general solution I'm referring to is a modified version of Eq.(4,38) in the source mentioned: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09580 
But I do believe this could most likely be wrong since my version is a non-dimensionalised form, rather than working with dimensional units.

Comment: Yes, I agree that your equation seems reasonable under that view. In that regard that was a bit of a false lead but it did fix the other typo. As for the link (@Sal): I accidentally included a spurious period at the end. Remove that and it works fine.

Comment: Is $|\psi|^2=\psi^*\psi$?

Comment: I believe you should have $-2iu\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ as opposed to $-2iu\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier when calculating derivatives etc, we let $\eta = x-ut$ where $u$ is the speed of our travelling soliton. So now we can calculate the necessary derivatives in order to substitute them into our original nondimensional GPE:
\begin{align}\label{eq: equation eta derivatives}
\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} &= \frac{df}{d\eta} e^{-i\mu t}, \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t} &= -u\frac{df}{d\eta} e^{-i\mu t} - i\mu f(\eta)e^{-i\mu t}, \hspace{1em} \text{(using product rule)} \\
|\psi|^2 \psi &= f^3 e^{-i\mu t}.
\end{align}
So after substituting these derivatives into our original equation, we have the following:
\begin{align}
 2iu \frac{df}{d\eta} e^{-i\mu t} &= \frac{d^2 f}{d\eta^2}e^{-i\mu t} +f\,(2\mu -|f|^2)\,e^{-i\mu t}, \\
   \tag{1}\label{eq: soleq to be solved} 2iu \frac{df}{d\eta} &= \frac{d^2f}{d\eta^2} +f\,(2\mu -|f|^2).
\end{align}
Since wave-functions are not typically real-valued, we do not assume that $f(\eta)$ is real-valued. Hence we can write this in complex form: $f=f_{1} +if_{2}. $ Now after substituting this and taking only the imaginary part of this, we obtain the following:
\begin{equation}
2u \frac{d f_1}{d\eta} = \frac{d^2 f_2}{d\eta^2} + f_2 (2\mu -f_{1}^{2}-f_{2}^{2}).
\end{equation}
This can now be solved by treating $f_{2}$ as a constant, which can be seen by looking at what type of solution you would find from the imaginary part of \eqref{eq: soleq to be solved}. Without loss of generality we let $f_{2} = 2u$, then solving the following nonlinear separable ODE:
\begin{equation}\label{soliton2}
    \frac{d f_1}{d\eta} = 2\mu -f_{1}^{2}-f_{2}^{2},
\end{equation}.
After some separation and integration we obtain the following result:
\begin{align}
    \eta &= -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\mu -4u^2}} \arctan \Big(\frac{if_1}{\sqrt{2\mu -4u^2}}\Big)+c \\
    &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu - 4u^2}}\, \text{arctanh}\, \Big(\frac{f_1}{\sqrt{2\mu -4u^2}}\Big)+c, \hspace{1em}\text{(c is constant)}
\end{align}
which yields the following final answer, after applying limits:
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{dark soliton solution}
    \psi(x,t) &= \Big(\zeta \tanh \big[\zeta(x-ut)\big]+i\,2u\Big)\,e^{-i\mu t}, \\
    \text{with}\hspace{2em} \zeta &= \sqrt{2\mu -4u^2}\,.
\end{align}
I plotted this dark soliton solution in Matlab with different speed values, I will leave my plot attached.
Thank you to all those who commented and gave advice and guidance, this answer and plot was completed as part of my Year 3 Maths Research Project surrounding vortex interaction in a superfluid.

[image: This is the soliton solution found in \eqref{dark soliton solution}.]